# pandas converts all values in excel to zero because there is a = sign in front of values

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xls

I have this Excel file (xls) in S3 bucket. With Python I pull it down, then with pandas, I read it, convert it to pandas frame then write the frame to CSV. CSV is produced and all values are zero.

one thing I noticed is that the values have a = sign in the front of the numbers as shown below.

as soon as pandas reads the xls all numbers get converted to zero. If I manually open the xls and remove the = sign from the first value in the first row then all the values for that column are ok and not converted to zero

`

```
    s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, 'converter/xlsxtocsv/TEMP.xls')
    df = pd.read_excel("converter/xlsxtocsv/TEMP.XLS")
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("converter/xlsxtocsv/TEMP1.csv")
```

[image of values in excel cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXTSZ.png)
`

Pic of what values in the cell look like, when you go into one you see an = sign

I've tried reading as bytes and using xlrd but nothing is working. it seems as soon as the xls is opened in any way it just converts everything to zero.

Comment: The prefix "=" sign usually there is formula associated with the cell so how to export  the value not the formula, see this answer, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/need-to-export-values-instead-of-the-formula-is-this-possible/m-p/1317133